# Scroll bar position

Tags: html, css

with a click I want to position the scroll bar to a specific div. I use this code:

```
<a href="#sponsor">Go to Sponsor</a>
...
<div id="sponsor">Sponsor</div>
```

The problem is that my header is fixed (with height 50px) and overlap the div#sponsor itself.

See here http://jsfiddle.net/xqZ9y/

How to solve?

Thank you.

Comment: can you please create a fiddle (www.jsfiddle.net) of what you have done so far?

Comment: Add a 50px or more `padding-top` to the `div#sponsor` under your header ?

Comment: the scrollbar clicking is irrelevant. you need to create a working layout. right now you should have the same problem even if you scroll manually.

Comment: Brewal, adding padding means to change the layout

Answer (score 2):

the problem is that a standard anchor will take you to the target by setting the scrollTop of the document to be the offset top of the target.  In your case this means that the item is positioned behind your header.  One way you can get around this is to override the anchor click event to compensate for the header height when the item is repositioned.

Here is some jQuery that would do this...

```
$(function(){
    $("a[href^='#']").on("click.scrollFix", function(e) {
        // cancel the click of the a href from taking you to the 
        // anchor by normal means
        e.preventDefault();        

        // instead find the element and scroll to the elements position - the height of the     header
        var targetSelector = $(this).attr("href"),
            targetTop = $(targetSelector).offset().top,
            headerHeight = $("#header").outerHeight(true);

        $(document).scrollTop(targetTop - headerHeight);
    });
});
```

and here's a working fiddle with an example using a fixed header and some junk content :)

http://jsfiddle.net/QjheK/

Answer (score 1):

You can bypass the problem by adding an additional element, positioned correctly with the `#sponsor`

```
<span id="sponsor"></span>
```

```css
#sponsor {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: relative:
    top: 50px;
}
```